# Xamarin: can not debug on laptop but work on desktop

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I was able to plug in Nexus 4 on my desktop and debug with it. However, when I switch to my laptop and running the code. I can't debug with Nexus 4 plug in. When I hit f5 or click on the Nexus 4 from the device list. Visual Studio run then it stop. Nothing happened. Does anyone know why it work on my desktop but not on my laptop?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro with latest Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when sharing a device between two different development PC's. The solve for me was to uninstall the app before allowing the other computer to install and debug.

Additionally, you may need to check the application manager list and make sure the application has been properly uninstalled (i.e. there was some cached data that showed up under the package name of the app in the application manager list than needed to be uninstall).